# Split C program into separate files when some variables are needed by both

Tags: c, file, global-variables

I'm trying to figure out how to split a program I have into separate components and it's giving me a lot of trouble.  I have a command line game that I want to split into a setup file and a gameplay file.

Splitting up the functionality is easy, but dealing with these two variables that both programs need has proven to be difficult.  I need the `directory` variable and the `rooms` variable to be accessible from the gameplay file.

I feel like I have to be missing something obvious.  I've tried `extern`, tried writing the variables to temp files, but every way I try has some hiccup.  What is the most straightforward way of doing this?

When using `extern`, I get an error compiling with `gcc -o prog prog.c -lpthread`

```
extern char directory[20];
extern char *rooms[7];
```

The errors:

```
5 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_directory", referenced from:
      _createRooms in eldridgt-6bd105.o
      _connectionsToFiles in eldridgt-6bd105.o
      _roomTypesToFiles in eldridgt-6bd105.o
  "_rooms", referenced from:
      _createRooms in eldridgt-6bd105.o
      _connectionsToFiles in eldridgt-6bd105.o
      _roomTypesToFiles in eldridgt-6bd105.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct stat st = {0};
const char * ROOM_NAMES[] = {"Water", "Fire", "Wind", "Earth", "Plasma", "DarkMatter", "Air", "Ice", "Rock", "Lava"};
int i,j;
char directory[20];
char *rooms[7];
int connections[7][7] = {0};
int totalMoves = 0;
char roomChoice[20];
char *movesRecord[100];
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void getRoomChoice() {
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", roomChoice);
    fflush(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void * getTime(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    FILE *file = fopen("currentTime.txt", "w");
    time_t curtime;
    struct tm *loc_time;
    curtime = time (NULL);
    loc_time = localtime (&curtime);
    fprintf(file, "%s\n", asctime (loc_time));
    fclose(file);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void * createRooms() {
  // Create directory
  int pid = getpid();
  char prefix[] = "eldridgt.";
  sprintf(directory, "%s%d", prefix, pid);
  if (stat(directory, &st) == -1) {
    mkdir(directory, 0700);
  }

  // Get random non-repeating array from 0-6
    int randArray[10];
    int x, p;
    int count;
    int i=0;
    srand(time(NULL)); // Random seed
    for(count=0;count<10;count++){
            randArray[count]=rand()%10+1;
    }
    while(i<7){
            int r=rand()%7;
            for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
                    if(randArray[x]==r){
                            break;
                    }
            }
            if(x==i){
                    randArray[i++]=r;
            }
    }

    // Create room files
  for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
    int random;
        int x;
        int randomArray[7];
    char filePath[100];
    int connectionArr[10];
    memset(connectionArr, 0, sizeof connectionArr);
    random = randArray[i];
    if (connectionArr[random] == 0) { // If room not used
      sprintf(filePath,"%s/%s", directory, ROOM_NAMES[random]);
      FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "ab+");
      fprintf(file, "ROOM NAME: %s\n", ROOM_NAMES[random]); // Add room name
      fclose(file);
      rooms[i] = ROOM_NAMES[random];
      connectionArr[random] = 1; // Room has been used
    }
  }
  return rooms;
}

void * createConnections() {
    for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
        int connectionCount = rand() % 4 + 3; // Random number 3-6
        int currentCount = 0;
        for(j=0; j<7; j++) {
            currentCount = currentCount + connections[i][j];
        }
        while (currentCount < connectionCount+1) {
            int random = rand() % 7;
            while (random == i) {
                random = rand() % 7; // If random == current, reset random
            }
      // Set connections between both rooms
            connections[i][random] = 1;
            connections[random][i] = 1;
            currentCount++;
        }
    }
}

void * connectionsToFiles() {
    for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
        int connectionCount = 1;
        for(j=0; j<7; j++) {
            if(connections[i][j] == 1) {
        char filePath[100];
                sprintf(filePath,"%s/%s", directory, rooms[i]);
                FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "ab+");
                fprintf(file, "CONNECTION %d: %s\n", connectionCount, rooms[j]);
                fclose(file);
                connectionCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void * roomTypesToFiles() {
    for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
    char filePath[100];
        sprintf(filePath,"%s/%s", directory, rooms[i]);
        FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "a");
    switch(i) {
      case 0 :
        fprintf(file, "ROOM TYPE: START_ROOM\n");
        break;
      case 6 :
        fprintf(file, "ROOM TYPE: END_ROOM\n");
        break;
      default :
        fprintf(file, "ROOM TYPE: MID_ROOM\n");
    }
        fclose(file);
    }
}

isEndRoom(idx) {
    movesRecord[totalMoves - 1] = rooms[idx];
  char filePath[100];
    sprintf(filePath,"%s/%s", directory, rooms[idx]);
    char roomType[20];
    int lineNumber = 1;
    FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "r");
    int totaLines = 0;
    char line[256];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        totaLines++; // Line count of room file
    }
    fclose(file);

    file = fopen(filePath, "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        if(lineNumber == totaLines) {
      int length = strlen(line) - 11;
            strncpy(roomType, line+11, length);
            roomType[length-1] = '\0';
        }
        lineNumber++;
    }

    // Check if this is the end room
    if(strncmp(roomType, "END", 3) == 0) {
    printf("YOU HAVE FOUND THE END ROOM. CONGRATULATIONS!\n");
    printf("YOU TOOK %d STEPS. YOUR PATH TO VICTORY WAS:\n", totalMoves - 1);
    for(i=1; i<totalMoves; i++) {
      printf("%s\n", movesRecord[i]);
    }
        return 1; // End was reached
    } else {
    return 0; // End was not reached
  }
}

void * playGame(idx) {
  totalMoves++;
  printf("\n");
    if(isEndRoom(idx)) {
        exit(0);
    }

    while(1) {
    char filePath[100];
        sprintf(filePath,"%s/%s", directory, rooms[idx]);

        FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "r");
        int totaLines = 0;
        char line[100];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
            totaLines++; // Line count of room file
        }
        fclose(file);

        file = fopen(filePath, "r");
        int lineNumber = 0;
        char *roomChoices[6][20];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) { // Current room name
            if(lineNumber == 0) {
                char roomName[20];
        int length = strlen(line) - 11;
            strncpy(roomName, line+11, length);
            roomName[length-1] = '\0';
                printf("CURRENT LOCATION: %s\n", roomName);
            }
            else if(lineNumber == 1) { // First room choice option
                printf("POSSIBLE CONNECTIONS: ");
                fflush(stdout);
                char roomName[20];
        int length = strlen(line) - 14;
            strncpy(roomName, line+14, length);
            roomName[length-1] = '\0';
                printf("%s", roomName);
                strcpy(roomChoices[lineNumber - 1], roomName);
            }
            else if(lineNumber > 1 && lineNumber < totaLines - 1) { // Subsequent room choice options
                printf(", ");
                fflush(stdout);
                char roomName[20];
        int length = strlen(line) - 14;
            strncpy(roomName, line+14, length);
            roomName[length-1] = '\0';
                printf("%s", roomName);
                fflush(stdout);
                strcpy(roomChoices[lineNumber - 1], roomName);
            }
            else {
                printf(".");
                fflush(stdout);
            }
            lineNumber++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        printf("\nWHERE TO? >");
        getRoomChoice(); // Get next room choice
        if (strcmp(roomChoice, "time") == 0) {
            pthread_t thread;
            int rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &getTime, NULL);
            if (rc) {
                    printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                    exit(-1);
            }
            sleep(1);
            FILE *file = fopen("currentTime.txt", "r");
            char currentTime[50];
            fgets(currentTime, sizeof currentTime, file);
            printf("\n%s\n", currentTime);
        } else {
                for(i=0; i<totaLines-2; i++) {
                    if(strcmp(roomChoices[i], roomChoice) == 0) {
                        for(j=0; j<7; j++) {
                            if(strcmp(rooms[j], roomChoice) == 0) { // If the room is equal to roomChoice
                                playGame(j); // Make playGame call for new room
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                printf("\nHUH? I DON’T UNDERSTAND THAT ROOM. TRY AGAIN.\n\n");
                fflush(stdout);
                fflush(stdin);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    createRooms();
    createConnections();
    connectionsToFiles();
    roomTypesToFiles();
    playGame(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your C textbook or tutorial should explain how to use `extern` variables to share variables between different source files.

Comment: With global variables it's very easy since all you have to do is to declare them as `extern` in the other files. Not that I really recommend using global variables though.

Comment: Also, doing `fflush` in an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is really *undefined behavior*. Don't do it if you want to be portable.

Comment: Try recoding your application so it doesn't need global variables to be shared between the files, but passes everything as function parameters and return values.

Comment: If you need help getting the `extern` approach to work then please show your best attempt that did not work so we can point out the exact problem. But best to avoid needing global variables if you can.

Comment: @kaylum Updated the question with the issue I'm getting with extern.

Comment: That's the error. But we also need the exact and complete code that generates that error. And you also need to provide how you are building the program.

Comment: @kaylum I added what I'm using to compile, but I don't know what you mean by what code generates that error...the error occurs when compiling the whole program.

Comment: Where is the code that uses the variables. You need to show at least two files right? One that defines the variable and the other that uses it via extern. But the problem looks like you are not building correctly. `gcc -o prog prog.c -lpthread` that can't be right. If you have multiple files then the link needs to link multiple .o files into the final executable.

Comment: Or are you building two seperate programs? If that is the case then `extern` is not going to help you as that is for a single program. You need Interprocess Communication (IPC) if you want to share data between different programs.

Comment: @kaylum I clearly don't understand how extern works, or how to compile something used externally, do you know of a good resource for that?  The documentation I've been looking through hasn't been helpful at all.

Comment: Well, you need to define your requirements clearly before we can even say whether `extern` is what you need. So are you building one single executable or multiple executables that need to share data?

Comment: @kaylum I have two files - one that does setup for the game, the other one that plays it.  The setup file defines the directory and rooms variables, and I need to be able to use those in a separate gameplay file.  So multiple executables.

Comment: Well then `extern` is not what you need. `extern` is for a single executable. It tells the compiler that there is a variable of that name and type in a different file but will be accessible to the program at runtime because it is in the same process. If you have seperate executables then you need IPC - that's too broad a topic to cover here. But the takeaway is that extern is not appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: I think, you need a config file. Setup program will write into the file, and second process will read from it.